# Filter using multiple column condition, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe with 2 columns Actor1Name & ActionGeo_FullName and some 10K rows, want to filter records if any one column contains macao or macau

Below is my script, Is this correct one? Please let me know simple script.

```
dataMAC = dataAll.loc[dataAll['Actor1Name'].str.contains('macao|macau') == True  | dataAll['ActionGeo_FullName'].str.contains('macao|macau') == True]

Actor1Name  ActionGeo_FullName
macao   macau
US  USA
China   China
UK  United Kindom
China MC    macau
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think yes, a bit should be improved by removing `==True` and `loc`:

```
dataMAC = dataAll[dataAll['Actor1Name'].str.contains('macao|macau')  | 
                  dataAll['ActionGeo_FullName'].str.contains('macao|macau')]
print (dataMAC)
  Actor1Name ActionGeo_FullName
0      macao              macau
4      China           MC macau
```

Answer (score 1):

The True is active by default, so you don't need it.
And maybe the .loc function cannot accept these type of operation.

Comment: This is not really an answer. Could you provide a working code snippet?

Comment: Adding to @Risadinha, if you don't provide code, you will be saying basically the same as the already accepted answer (in which both the `==True` and the `.loc` are removed. Thanks!